# Automatically run macro when a value changes as the result of Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I want MyMacro to run automatically when the cell value in A1 changes according to a vlookup formula. MyMacro copies a row then pastes it to a different section of the worksheet when a condition dependant on the value of A1 is met.

I have tried variations of Target.Address and the following, which have not worked:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
Static OldVal As Variant
   If Range("A1").Value <> OldVal Then
      OldVal = Range("A1").Value

If Not Intersect(Target(1), Range("C1401:I140")) Is Nothing Then
If Range("A1").Value < ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value Then
    Range("C140:I140").Value = Range("B55:H55").Value
        ElseIf Range("B55").Value > ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value Then
         Range("C140:I140").Formula = ""
End If
  End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub MyMacro()

Worksheet_Calculate ([C140])

End Sub
```

With this, MyMacro only works when I manually hit Run Macro after each time A1 changes. How can I get this to be automatic?

Thanks.

Comment: If you go into the VBE and select the Calculate event from the drop down you will see that it does not have any parameters, and sadly you can't just add them manually and hope it will work.

Comment: So maybe use an event based on a source cell. I'm sure there are plenty of examples online.

Comment: Unrelated note: check out this cool [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to clean up the indentation.

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles at all. Event handler signatures can't be messed with - they have the parameters they are defined with, and tweaking the signature can only ever break things. `Worksheet.Calculate` is fired whenever *the worksheet* calculates.

Comment: Do you really mean **Range("C1401:I140")** in Line 6 of your code ?  I suspect you mean Range("C140:I140").

Comment: Ah thanks, you're right

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when the value of your calculated Cell A1 changes then use the Worksheet**_Change** event on the relevant worksheet.

(Find the worksheet in the VBA editor and right-click to select "view code")

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("$A$1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
         ... [call your change_routine]
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and @BigBen for the indenter. However when I added the above line, MyMacro stopped responding (there was no error message, just nothing happened) after A1 changed and after A1 changed and I clicked Run Macro.

Comment: If you followed the instructions for where to add this code (in the Worksheet_Change event on the relevant worksheet) then you can easily verify that it indeed executes when cell A1 is changed simply by adding a Msgbox call or a breakpoint in the code where I had **"[call your change routine]"**. Then single-step (using [F8] key to see why your code is not doing what you expect.

Comment: It's also unclear whether you want your routine to execute when A1 changes, or a cell in Row 140 columns C to I.  If you call your (confusingly named) Worksheet_Calculate routine by passing the same **Target** passed into Worksheet_Change above then cell A1 will fail your intersect routine for row 140 and your routine will do nothing. :-)

Comment: Hi Rina, I note that you didn't respond to any of my comments.  If you found the answer helpful please mark it as an answer. Thanks.